# Lower semi continuity for the norm of the speed

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, functions, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be a smooth bounded open domain in $\mathbb R^d$. Let $\gamma_n: [0,1]\to \overline{\Omega}$ be a sequence of Lipschitz functions which converges uniformly on $[0,1]$ to a Lipshitz function $\gamma : [0,1]\to \overline{\Omega}$.

Does one have for all $t\in [0,1]$

$$\liminf \vert \gamma_n' (t)\vert \geq \vert \gamma'(t)\vert,$$

where ' stands for $d/dt$.   (?)

And if not, does one have a counterexample ?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: I assume you mean the derivative almost everywhere?

Comment: Yes from Rademacher's THM.